# Disable windows shortcut keys using C# or Java application

Tags: c#, java, registry, keyboard-shortcuts

I need some tips in how can I disable shortcut keys in Windows, while running an application. I need simple application, which when is started all the shortcut keys are disabled, including ctrl+c,ctrl+v,alt+tab, etc. It can be Java application or C# application, don't matter. After exiting the application, everything should be normal again. Perhaps, should access the registry. Any help will be useful, also and some simple code :)

Regards